# Unable to deploy Flask application in EC2 ("Site does not exist")

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, amazon-ec2, flask

I have my php based apps running on my server on AWS EC2 (Apache2, Ubuntu 14.04). I'm trying to deploy a Flask application on a sub domain. Since I don't have any experience in deploying Flask applications, I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/) tutorial.

This is my virtual host file:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myFlaskApp/myFlaskApp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/myFlaskApp/myFlaskApp/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/myFlaskApp/myFlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/myFlaskApp/myFlaskApp/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I saved this file as `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.domain.com.config`. When I tried `sudo a2ensite sub.domain.com.config`. It's throwing  `Site sub.domain.com.config does not exist!`.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the file from:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.domain.com.config
```

To:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.domain.com.conf
```

And `a2ensite sub.domain.com` will see the file.